# Extended Euclidean Algorithm in Z3 Python API

Tags: python, z3, smt

I'm trying to model the extended Euclidean algorithm in Z3, but ran into infinite loop.

Suggestions and comments welcome.

The first function is coded in Python - just for reference only.

The second function is the one that ran into an infinite loop when z3 was analyzing it.

Do you see any mistake in how I mapped my regular Python function to the corresponding Z3 syntax?

```
'''
Returns d, x, y such that a*x + b*y = d
d = gcd(a, b)
'''
def extended_euclid_rec(a, b):
    if b == 0:
       d = a; x = 1; y = 0 # y can be any int
       return d, x, y
    else:
       d, x1, y1 = extended_euclid_rec(b, a % b)
       q = a // b
       x = y1
       y  = x1-y1*q
       assert a*x + b*y == d
       return d, x, y
```

This function gets into an infinite loop.

```
def extended_euclid(a, b):
   d = If(b == 0, a, extended_euclid(b, a % b)[0])
   x1 = If(b == 0, 1, extended_euclid(b, a % b)[1])
   y1 = If(b == 0, 0, extended_euclid(b, a % b)[2])

   q = If(b == 0, 1, a // b)
   x = If(b == 0, 1, y1)
   y = If(b == 0, 0, x1-y1*q)
   return d, x, y


a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')

s = Solver()
s.add(extended_euclid(a, b)[0] == 1)
print s.sexpr()
print s.check()
```

Comment: Well, your function calls itself unconditionally, so it has unbounded recursion. Do you actually need to model the process of this algorithm, or do you just need to represent a constraint that two integers are coprime?

Comment: Thanks. I need to model the process of this algorithm. If b == 0, then the recursion should stop, which is the case in the first function that works well in Python - assuming the depth of the recursion is correctly set.

Comment: `b` is a formal variable, it cannot equal zero at the time you are calling your function because it does not have a value at that time. And your function calls itself unconditionally, `If` is not actually branching here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're running the function with a symbolic input, and hence the recursion never stops. You cannot model recursive functions like this directly using Python functions, unless you guarantee that the recursion will stop concretely.

A classic trick is to pass an extra counter to the function, which will be a regular integer (not a z3 symbolic integer!), that gets decremented in each recursive call. So long as the count is large enough, you can get verification done this way. But determining how large a count should be depends on the algorithm you want to model, and might be hard to determine.

The other alternative is to use the recursive-function definition capabilities of z3, where you write the function recursively as a z3py function (not a Python function). However, this is rather tricky as well, because most recursive functions will need inductive proofs, and SMT solvers don't do induction.

To sum up, z3 (or any other SMT solver) isn't really the right tool to model this sort of recursive programs. Instead, use a proper theorem prover such as Isabelle, ACL2, Coq, Lean, etc; all of which support such recursive definitions out-of-the box. While these tools are are not push-button, they offer a lot of proof-automation to help you along.